# How is a merge left or a merge right chosen?

Tags: civil-engineering, highway-engineering

Recently a certain 2 lane exit ramp changed from merge right to merge left, but the entrance ramp immediately preceding it is merge right. Why was this changed? In a given circumstance, what dictates a merge left rather than a merge right?

Comment: Might be beneficial to share the region of the world.

Comment: Presumably, somebody decided to change which of the merging roads had priority over the other one. Unless somebody else here knows the traffic patterns at that particular road junction, I don't think you will get a better answer than that.

Comment: Please post a diagram of the roads and ramps in question.  It's not obvious where these merges occur.

Comment: Is this in a drive-on-the-left or in a drive-on-the-right country?